# Strange loop output - Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

Wy are these loops:

```
while (x <= gridWidth) {
            while (y <= gridHeight) {
                System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }
```

outputting this:

```
    X: 0, Y: 0
    X: 0, Y: 1
    X: 0, Y: 2
    X: 0, Y: 3
    X: 0, Y: 4
    X: 0, Y: 5
    X: 0, Y: 6
    X: 0, Y: 7
    X: 0, Y: 8
    X: 0, Y: 9
    X: 0, Y: 10
    X: 0, Y: 11
    X: 0, Y: 12
    X: 0, Y: 13
    X: 0, Y: 14
    X: 0, Y: 15
    X: 0, Y: 16
    X: 0, Y: 17
    X: 0, Y: 18
    X: 0, Y: 19
    X: 0, Y: 20
    X: 0, Y: 21
    X: 0, Y: 22
    X: 0, Y: 23
    X: 0, Y: 24
    X: 0, Y: 25
    X: 0, Y: 26
    X: 0, Y: 27
    X: 0, Y: 28
    X: 0, Y: 29
    X: 0, Y: 30
    X: 0, Y: 31
    X: 0, Y: 32
    X: 0, Y: 33
    X: 0, Y: 34
    X: 0, Y: 35
    X: 0, Y: 36
    X: 0, Y: 37
    X: 0, Y: 38
    X: 0, Y: 39
    X: 0, Y: 40
    X: 0, Y: 41
    X: 0, Y: 42
    X: 0, Y: 43
    X: 0, Y: 44
    X: 0, Y: 45
    X: 0, Y: 46
    X: 0, Y: 47
    X: 0, Y: 48
    X: 0, Y: 49
    X: 0, Y: 50
```

?

I am very sure that `gridWidth = 50`, because I printed it.

Comment: that's the normal behavior if gridHeight = 50, what were you expecting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reset `y` back to zero before the nested loop starts. Otherwise, the outer loop will execute 50 times, but the last 49 times the inner loop will not execute at all, because `y` is already above `gridHeight`.

Comment: and a `for` loop is perfect for this: `for(y=0; y <= gridHeight; y++)`. If you don't need the value of `y` after the loop, you can even move the declaration into the `for`: `for(int y =0...`).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight didn't see your response, before posting

Comment: @yshavit I know that, but unfortunately I always screw up when I try to use a for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

As [Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) suggests in it's book [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), use the for construct instead of the while whenever you can. Is less error prone, more concise, and in effect it would have probably prevented your error.

```
for (int x=0;x <= gridWidth;x++)
    for (int y=0;y <= gridHeight;y++)
        System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't re initializing y with each loop

```
    while (x <= gridWidth) {
        y = 0;
        while (y <= gridHeight) {
            System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int y=0,x=0;
while (x <= gridWidth) {
   while (y <= gridHeight) {
    System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
    y++;
  }
x++;
y=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int gridWidth = 50, gridHeight = 50;

for(int x = 0; x <= gridWidth; x++)
  for(int y = 0; y <= gridHeight; y++)
    System.out.println("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
```